# Can we validate the response from google form whether entered value exists or not using google forms script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I need to collect unique data through google forms. So I have one primary key on first section, after submit of first section, if this value exists I need to display error message on this section otherwise move to next section where I collect all the data. Can this be possible through google form script ?

Comment: How is the primary key entered?

Comment: For my form I have taken mobile number as primary key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique field validation in Google forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708091/unique-field-validation-in-google-forms)